# setuptools pyproject.toml equivalent to `python setup.py clean --all`

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm migrating from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml`. The commands to install my package appear to be the same, but I can't find what the `pyproject.toml` command for cleaning up build artifacts is. What is the equivalent to `python setup.py clean --all`?

Comment: Related discussion: https://discuss.python.org/t/custom-build-targets-for-cleanup-post-pep-518/13741

Answer (score 7):

The distutils command [clean](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.clean) is not needed for a `pyproject.toml` based build. Modern tools invoking [PEP517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/)/[PEP518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) hooks, such as [build](https://pypi.org/project/build/), create a temporary directory or a cache directory to store intermediate files while building, rather than littering the project directory with a `build` subdirectory.

Anyway, it was [not really an exciting command](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/distutils/command/clean.py) in the first place and `rm -rf build` does the same job.

Comment: This isn't true for me in practice, at least with the current way `setuptools` implements `pyproject.toml`. Right now, `build` is making a <project-name>.egg-info directory inside of my existing /data directory and does not clean it up.

Comment: @lmhamilt Which part is not true?  The egg-info subdirectory holds the package metadata, it's not quite a temporary build artifact like a build subdirectory is. I recommend to add `*.egg-info` to your global gitignore patterns and _not_ clean this directory, because it is actually useful to have in some cases such as a metadata provider for editable installations. Note that `python setup.py clean --all` will not have removed the egg-info directory either.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying. I think I got a little turned around from [the discussion on a github issue about clean & .egg-info](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1347). I know it's being put there because I have package data, but I guess I'm still not clear on what it's for since it's not in the binary or wheel that will actually be distributed.

Comment: @lmhamilt The same info actually does go into the wheel, but it will be a .dist-info subdirectory with a slightly different structure (e.g. the PKG-INFO will be called METADATA). I believe the .dist-info subdirectory actually gets generated from the egg-info, although setuptools will probably change this to skip the egg and just generate dist-info directly at some stage in the future.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue when I was migrating. What wim answered seems to be mostly true.

If you do as the `setuptools` documentation says and use `python -m build` then the `build` directory will not be created, but a `dist` will.

However if you do `pip install .` a `build` directory will be left behind even if you are using a `pyproject.toml` file. This can cause issues if you change your package structure or rename files as sometimes the old version that is in the `build` directory will be installed instead of your current changes.

Personally I run `pip install . && rm -rf build` or `pip install . && rmdir /s /q build` for Windows. This could be expanded to remove any other unwanted artifacts.