# two copies of source code being checked by flake8 in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, continuous-integration, setuptools

When I run `flake8 .`, it runs on two copies of my source code:

```
./build/lib/smartx/smartpressing/frlo/silver/tagenriched.py:14:13: E225 missing whitespace around operator
./smartx/smartpressing/frlo/silver/tagenriched.py:14:13: E225 missing whitespace around operator
```

And because of it, I get duplicates of every issue as seen above.

I don't need the copy that is saved in `./build`...

Here is my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[project]
name = "mip"
version = "0.1.0"
license = {file = "LICENSE"}
description = "source code to run on mip databricks instance"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"

authors =  [
    {name = "MIP engineers"},
]

dependencies = [
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pyspark==3.5.0",
    "flake8==6.1.0",
    "mypy==1.6.1",
    "pandas-stubs==2.1.1.230928",
    "pytest==7.4.3",
    "pytest-cov==4.1.0",
    "isort==5.12.0"
]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And here is my CI `.yaml` file:

```
pool:
  name: SelfHosted-Linux
  demands: 
  - Agent.Name -equals az02 

strategy:
  matrix:
    Python310:
      python.version: '3.10'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    pip install '.[test]'
  displayName: 'Install Packages'

- script: |
    pip list
    flake8 . --count --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics --ignore=W291,E302,W503,W292 --exclude notebooks --color always
  displayName: 'Run flake8 code checks'

- script: |
    mypy .
  displayName: 'Run mypy type-hinting checks'

- script: |
    pytest
  displayName: 'Run pytest'

- script: |
    isort --diff --check .
  displayName: 'Run isort'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflake8%5D+exclude+directory

Comment: Sure I could exclude the directory, but a cleaner solution would be to not have this `./build/lib` directory created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74659682/5392289) SO answer, I have added this line of code:

```
pip install '.[test]' && rm -rf build
```

Doesn't seem like the cleanest of solutions but it does the job.